# Flutter TextField doesn't respect maxLength limit even when using LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter after version 1.20.0

Tags: flutter, dart

Testing the same code with Flutter 1.20.0 we have different behavior (the correct one). I also believe maxLength should be respected all the time.
**sample code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
                   inputFormatters: [
                     LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
                                  ],
            maxLength: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: what i meant]

Comment: I am using Flutter 2.0.0 and I can't reproduce your issue with your exact same code. - `Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-GB)`

Comment: please do not put spaces between characters here is the tip

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. I have taken your code and run the app with Flutter 2.0. I did not put any spaces between characters, and it limits the field to 5 characters. I also don't understand what you mean by "here is the tip".